# Grayscale setting reverts back after reboot

Tags: android, oneplusone

I am using one plus 10r android mobile. I would like to use grayscale monochrome mode permanently, but this setting erased after every reboot. As I do auto shutdown and auto start at night time. Is there a way so that grayscale setting is setted permanently and reboot should not affect it.